# Static building of Qt 5.7.0 fails to complete when using MinGW 6.3.0

Tags: python, c++, qt, powershell, mingw

Recently, I have managed to build static Qt 5.7.0 using MinGW 5.3.0 that came with dynamic version. For, how I did this, I have followed the steps from the link:

https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW

No errors came out during building of the static Qt (expect (MANY) warnings about deprecated `std::auto_ptr`). After setting Qt Version and Kit in Qt Creator, it successfully produced statically linked executable (no even `CONFIG += static` was required).

**But**, it seems that code can be compiled only with the version of MinGW that static Qt have been built with, where this condition wasn't present in dynamic version, since I could compile and link Qt code with both MinGW 5.3.0 and MinGW 6.3.0. Trying to use MinGW 6.3.0 with static Qt (built with MinGW 5.3.0) produces many undefined reference errors like:

```
error: undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int)'
```

So it seems no single Qt library is linked here (`qmake` is not compatible or something).

But that didn't discourage me. I just followed the steps from link again, but now building static Qt with MinGW 6.3.0 (flags can be set to let script know which version of MinGW to use).

It was promising, script was building Qt for about 50 minutes, then the error halted the whole process:

```
// [...millions of console lines...]
cd qtdeclarative\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\qtbase\bin\qmake C:\Qt\
Static\src\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0\qtdeclarative\qtdeclarative.pro -o Makefile ) && D:/Programming_Tools/Nuwe
n/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile install
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Project ERROR: Building QtQml requires Python.
MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:338: module-qtdeclarative-install_subtargets] Error 3
MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe: Target 'install' not remade because of errors.
Press Enter to continue...:
```

The most important part here is of course `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Now, that's **STRANGE**, because I have python 3.5.2 set in Environmental Variables PATH.

I tried to call python in the PowerShell after this, and here is the outcome:

```
PS C:\Users\Ebisu\Downloads> python
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Now, I opened new PowerShell session, and called python again. Here is the outcome:

```
PS C:\Users\Ebisu\Downloads> python
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
PS C:\Users\Ebisu\Downloads>
```

Now my mind has been blown. What? I tried to run the script in the this new session again, but it halted in the same spot, and **AGAIN**, python is not recognized after it. How is it possible? How can python become invisible during run of the script?

Also note, I managed to use `qmake.exe` that came out of this halted build, and it does compile and link Qt code with MinGW 6.3.0, expect it can't use any modules like `QT += multimedia` (not as bad as I expected, but still I would like to use modules).

Comment: I can only say its pretty interesting on the context that the results vary each time during calling python. Have you checked the environmental variables? I believe its proper but just want to cross check if the path has been mentioned properly

Comment: @RanadipDutta Yes, it is set properly. When calling `path` from PowerShell python directory is there, both before running script, after and in new session.

Comment: @RanadipDutta Ok, after double checking the $env:Path has been overwritten with script, not sure how I missed that. Now I'm trying to rebuild Qt with modified script.

Comment: Superb.Then that eases out lot of things :)

Answer (score 0):

Just coming across the same issue. I just wanted to add that in my case, fixing the path to include python didn't help as $env:PYTHONPATH was still pointing to my python3 installation and then the script was throwing a different error

```
((File "Lib/site.py", line 176
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax).
```

Adding one of these lines in the powershell script fixes the error:

```
$env:PYTHONPATH = "$MingwDir\opt\bin"
```

or

```
$env:PYTHONPATH = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt configure script caches prerequisite test results in file 'config.cache'. Script writes error message again and again, even if you already have python path added to PATH. Just delete it to force this test run again.